# Docker - COPY file from different working directory to another is not working

Tags: docker, copy

I'm using:

```
Docker 18.09.1
Ubuntu 16.04
```

I want to copy a file from a specific folder from my docker image to another folder in my docker image using the `Dockerfile`.

My `docker` commands are:

```
sudo docker build -t mytest .
sudo docker run mytest
```

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN mkdir -p out/
COPY . out/            <---- this works
COPY /usr/bin/yes /opt <---- this doesn't work!!

CMD out/helloworld
```

I have a `C++` application called `helloworld` on my `out/` working folder. However, I want to copy a file called `"yes"` which is under `/user/bin/` to my `/opt` folder.

I've tried the `COPY` command and also the `CMD` command but without success.

I tried to check if the file was there by running the command on my `Ubuntu` VM:

```
docker run mytest ls -l /opt
total 0
```

My COPY try:

```
COPY /usr/bin/yes /opt
```

My CMD try:

```
CMD ["cp /usr/bin/yes /opt"]
```

Error:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder737799611/usr/bin/yes: no such file or directory
```

Both doesn't work. How can I copy a file to another folder (inside the same docker image)?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the file from the host into the image, or between two directories inside the image?

Comment: Betweek two directories inside the image

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is stated here that you **cannot** use absolute path to copy file from your host to your container. It is not supported: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4592. So you have to prepare all your files in your current directory first.

Comment: By using: COPY /usr/bin/yes /opt/ 
I get the error:
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder737799611/usr/bin/yes: no such file or directory

Comment: thanks but this is not what I need..I don't want to copy files from my VM to the docker image. I just want to copy files between the filesystem on my docker image.

Comment: Yes but the issue is closed and absolute path is not supported: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4592

Comment: That is the answer. Can you please write that on as an answer so I can close this thread?

Answer (score 15):

The `COPY` command copies files from the build context (that's the `.` at the end of the `docker build` command in your example, aka the current directory) into the image. You cannot copy files from outside of the build context into the image.

For your purposes, it appears you want to copy between two different locations inside your image, not from the build context at all. For that, as long as you have the `cp` command present in almost every base image, you can run:

```
RUN cp /usr/bin/yes /opt/
```

Or in the json/exec syntax:

```
RUN [ "cp", "/usr/bin/yes", "/opt/" ]
```

Note that the exec syntax requires you to separate the command any every argument into a separate json array entry. The exec syntax also will not be running a shell, so you cannot do things like variable expansion and I/O redirection, which isn't being done in this case.