Docker can't find internal dependency
I'm kinda new with Docker but I need to build my microservice applications and I have a structure where some of those applications use another application from my package, another "module" from IntalliJ's project view, it's defined on Maven's POM like this:
        <!-- Annerd Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.annerd</groupId>
            <artifactId>ams-commons-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

But when I build the my Dockerfile, it gives this error
50.53 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ams-findme: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.annerd.findme:ams-findme:jar:BETA-2.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.annerd:ams-commons-utilities:jar:1.2.0 (absent): Could not find artifact com.annerd:ams-commons-utilities:jar:1.2.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Which leads me to believe that I'm missing some steps here.
This is my Dockerfile
FROM maven:3.9.6-amazoncorretto-17-al2023 AS build-stage

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD . /usr/src/app

RUN mvn install -U

###############################################################

FROM openjdk:17-alpine AS production-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /usr/src/app/target/*.jar annerd-find-me-api.jar

EXPOSE 8785

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "annerd-find-me-api.jar", "-Xmx256m -Xms128m -Dspring.profiles.active=prod"]

My question is, the project builds correctly on IntelliJ's IDE with the provided POM, I don't have any repository server like Nexus or similar to provide this dependency which is what I'm suspecting I need, I'm planning on implementing one but still not there yet, is there a way to solve this problem without a repository? Am I missing something?

You mentioned it builds locally so it should work if that artifact is exists in the right path.
First of all, give a try to change your local maven repository of that maven project. I'm kinda suspecting that the project's repo is configured towards the other application as you mentioned in your question. If not, ignore this point.
Is there any error message during docker build? If not, check whether the artifact exists in the path /usr/src/app/target.
If so, copy that to specific artifact or all if you need since you used wildcard.

COPY --from=build-stage /usr/src/app/target/*.jar .
COPY --from=build-stage /usr/src/app/target/annerd-find-me-api.jar annerd-find-me-api.jar

Update:
According to our discussion under comments section, I understand the dependency is from another project and the module is not under your current project.
Let's say, you work on project-A but the module is belonging project-B, which your Dockerfile in project-A can't find that module because you add all into the layer from current path as follows ADD . /usr/src/app.
In your Dockerfile, specify the module path out of project-A, which points the path under project-B such as:

Dockerfile

FROM maven:3.9.6-amazoncorretto-17-al2023 AS build-stage

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD . /usr/src/app

COPY </path-to-project-B/annerd-find-me-api.jar> /usr/src/app/target/annerd-find-me-api.jar <=== This line changed

RUN mvn install -U

FROM openjdk:17-alpine AS production-stage
...
...

Bear mind that, the path to the actual module or artifact that you generated should be either static or dynamic file path up to your needs.
For instance, if the project-B path or module path can be changed dynamically, then you should define such as ~/project/project-B/target/module-name.jar or similar.

Yes, it builds locally on IntelliJ. You said changing local maven for the project? You mean changing the POM.xml? I can try adding the URL property in which it'll find the "common-utilities" dependency but do I need to build it first? And Docker doesn't give any error, just Maven exit code 1 saying that the build wasn't successful. Just adding, "common-utilities" doesn't "run", it is a data structure module so it doesn't even have its own Dockerfile, hope this isn't the issue here. I tried to look for the JAR but the console stays on read-only, saying it'll be used for other tasks!

Local maven repository meaning, the maven repo used locally. I'm not a Java developer so don't remember the details, but as I recall, it's under .m2 or something like that, local repository of maven is where all your project artifacts, dependency jars are stored.

Got it! This dependency that I'm trying to load isn't on Maven, it's a "local" dependency, another "project" or actually another module made by me that has to be compiled before installing other modules that requires it. On IntelliJ I can manually compile this module and then it automagically knows where to pick the said dependency but, inside Docker it's different. I want to know if I can, on the Dockerfile, compile this dependency OR if I'll need a repository manager, like Nexus

Ok, I get you. So, I will update in my post. Please see the update

Tried that and doesn't work. I feel like it'd work if the jar was in the same folder but, since my JAR is in another folder it just can't copy it, some searches lead me to a question saying that it doesn't support COPY files from my machine using an absolute path...? Is stated here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038295/docker-copy-file-from-different-working-directory-to-another-is-not-working). But honestly now it's just easier to set up a Nexus or any other free repo manager, even a NAS to download the JAR it's easier than this. I can accept your answer if that's ok!

Right, if the path is out of docker context, then it's impossible. So there're a few manipulate ways. You can go for it if it's better to wrap up as an artifact, then having an Artifactory running locally or on a container such JFrog OSS docker image. Let me know if you need anything else!

Oh wow! Thanks man! You're really kind! Not the point of the question but if you know some courses or tutorials to get started on JForg OSS or Nexus it'll be great! I'm trying to install Nexus on my server but no luck so far! Not even sure if it's free so was looking for a course, found one on YouTube but didn't had time to study it yet. Apart from that thank you so much for your help and attention!!!

You're welcome, happy to help you with that issue! You can take a look at JFrog installation document as well as Nexus in the following document. If you have any questions, please feel free to open up. I can help you to set it up.
